# YouTube API v3.0 recordingDetails from playlistItems

Tags: youtube-api

I am looking to get recordingDetails from items in a playlist or from the videos in a channel. So far I have only found the /videos method to respond with recordingDetails.

Answer (score 2):

1. From [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method, you should get [uploads playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads)
2. Then from [playlists->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), you will get video Ids.
3. With that video ids, you can do videos->list to get recordingDetails.

Comment: I was wondering if there is one call that can get me the list of videos and their recordingDetails. If not then can i get the list of videos that have recordingDetails.